# How to get a value generated inside "SetTimeout" outside of it

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout, angular2-directives

I have the following piece of code

```
setTimeout(()=>{ console.log("TIMED OUT DATA", this.fetchedData['__zone_symbol__value']) },3000);
```

I want to get the value of `this.fetchedData['__zone_symbol__value']` outside of the setTimeout. Is it even possible?

Comment: simply declare one variable outside and assigne this.fetchedData['__zone_symbol__value'] value to that variable

Comment: `__zone_symbol__value` looks like you you trying to access any unresolved promise. Maybe resolving promise is solution for your problem? `this.fetchedData.then((e) => { console.log(e); })`

Comment: @pArthsavadiya It doesnot work in my case becuase the value is being generated only inside the timeout.

Comment: @KarolTrybulec Yes, infact it actually is a problem on an unresolved promise as to resolve the promise i had to make the method 'async' and as the method is the data providing method of 'amCharts' it stops working so using to promise without using async method has led me till here where the thing i want is right there but cant access it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare it outside and reference it directly.

Like [here, in this working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rhb3bjcYxlyPFmN0H3Pm).

```
export class App {

  myData = false;

  constructor() {
   this.restart();
  }

  restart(){
    console.log("Changind data to false outside timeout");
    this.myData = false;

    setTimeout(()=>{ 
      console.log("TIMED OUT DATA", this.myData) 
      this.myData = true;
      console.log("TIMED OUT DATA changed", this.myData) 
    },3000);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to find where or to which varriable did you assign data to that is ONLY being displayed inside the timeout

Comment: I updated my answer, although I don't quite get what do you mean by "ONLY being displayed inside the timeout" :S